# Game exp and level up

Tags: c++

I've been making my C++ text game. Gone fairly well so far. I had a few delays with some mistakes I have made. Got most of that fixed up. Now I am working on the level up and experience points system.  And IDK how to keep that number updated so it's knowns that it reaches level 55. Here's the code:
(first program ever)

```
//#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

bool gameRunning = true;

char Yarra = 'P';
char Dragon = 'D';

char map[28];

class Player;

class Enemy {
private:
    int lvl;

public:
    int health;
    Enemy() {
        int randomNumber = rand();

        int enemy_life = (randomNumber % 7) + 2;
        health = enemy_life;
        lvl = 1;
    }

    void attack(Player& p);

    friend class Player;
};

class Final_dragon {
public:
    int lvl;
    int health;
    Final_dragon() {
        health = 10;
        lvl = 2;
    }

    void attack(Player& p);

    friend class Player;
};

class Player {
private:
public:
    int health;
    int exp;
    int lvl;
    Player(bool hero) {
        if(hero) {
            health = 100;
            lvl = 1;
            exp = 0;
        } else {
            health = 1;
        }
    }

    void attack(Enemy& e);
    void lvlUp(Player& p);

    friend class Enemy;
    friend class Final_boss;
};

void Player::attack(Enemy& e) {
    int randomNumber = rand();

    int dmg = (randomNumber % 2) + 0;

    cout << "\nYou've done " << dmg << " damage!" << endl;

    e.health -= dmg;
}

void Enemy::attack(Player& p) {
    // int randomNumber = rand();

    // int dmg = (randomNumber % 20) + 0;
    int dmg = 2;

    cout << "\nThe Enemy does " << dmg << " damage to you!\n" << endl;

    p.health -= dmg;
}

void Player::lvlUp(Player& p) {}

int main() {
    int display;
    char playerInput{};
    char move;
    char action;

    map[0] = Yarra;
    map[27] = Dragon;
    cout << "Map: " << map[0];

    for(display = 1; display < 27; display++) {
        map[display] = '*';
        cout << map[display];
    }
    cout << map[27];
    cout << endl
         << endl
         << "Press '1' Travel to another space on the board \n"
         << "Press '2' Dismount and explore the current space " << endl;
    display = 0; // Start at map[0]

    while(gameRunning == true) {
        Player p(true);
        do {
            cin >> move; // Get user input

            if(move == '1') // If input is '1'
            {
                srand(time(0));
                int dice = (int)(1 + rand() % 6);
                cout << "You moved: " << dice << " steps" << endl;
                map[display] = '*';       // Remove old location of player
                display = display + dice; // Increase display location
                map[display] = 'P';       // Insert player in new map array location
                cout << "Your current location: " << display
                     << endl; // Player current location
            }

            if(move == '2') // If input is '2'
            {
                cout << "Your current location: " << display
                     << endl; // Player current location
                srand(time(0));
                int monster_dice = (int)(1 + rand() % 14); // Random monster
                cout << "Monster location: " << monster_dice << endl
                     << endl; // monster location

                if(display == monster_dice) {
                    cout << "You've encountered a Enemy! Press \"a\" to attack"
                         << endl
                         << endl;

                    Enemy e;

                    cout << "HP of the monster you encounter: " << e.health << endl;
                    cin >> action;

                    if(action == 'a' || action == 'A') {
                        do {
                            p.attack(e);
                            cin.ignore(1);

                            if(p.health <= 0) {
                                system("CLS");
                                cout << "\t\n\nYou have died..." << endl;
                                cout << "\t\nGAME OVER!" << endl << endl;

                                return 0;
                            }

                            if(e.health >= 1) {
                                e.attack(p);
                                cin.ignore(1);
                            }
                        } while(e.health >= 0);
                        if(e.health <= 0) {
                            cout << "\n\nYou defeat the Enemy! *Vistory Music*\n"
                                 << endl;
                            cout << "You gained " << 100
                                 << " experience from the Boar." << endl;
                            p.exp += 100;
                        }
                        if(p.exp >= 200 && p.exp <= 300) {
                            cout << "\nYou've gone up to level 2!" << endl;
                            p.lvl++;
                            p.health += 50;
                        }
                        if(p.exp >= 300 && p.exp <= 400) {
                            cout << "\nYou've gone up to level 3!" << endl;
                            p.lvl++;
                            p.health += 40;
                        }
                        if(p.exp >= 400 && p.exp <= 500) {
                            cout << "\nYou've gone up to level 4!" << endl;
                            p.lvl++;
                            p.health += 50;
                        }
                        if(p.exp >= 600 && p.exp <= 700) {
                            cout << "\nYou've gone up to level 5!" << endl;
                            p.lvl++;
                            p.health += 50;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } while(move != '1');
        for(int x = 0; x <= 28; x++) {
            cout << map[x];
        }

        if(display == 27 || display > 27) // If player at end of map array, end game
        {
            Final_dragon d;

            if(p.lvl == 2) {
                cout << "Ready for the fight" << endl;
            } else {
                system("CLS");
                cout << "\nAlas, the dragons eyes stare at you and places you "
                        "under his spell. You try to move but fail to do so and "
                        "find yourself torched by the dragons fire.If only you had "
                        "more experience, you could have seen it coming."
                     << endl;
                cout << "\t\nGAME OVER!" << endl
                     << endl; // Show text explaining why game ended
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At Stack Overflow, we want question askers to post a minimal reproducibe test case. While you code replicates the problem, it also includes lots of code you don't need to replicate just this problem. That art of working out which pieces of code are relevant is a useful skill for you to gain, and often makes the problem more obvious

Comment: That said, this is pretty good for a beginner. In fact, I'm not even sure I see the problem. The Player class is already keeping track of both level and experience. Couldn't you just write `if(display >= 27 && p.lvl >= 5)`?

Comment: More info on [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does this even compile? `if(p.lvlUp == 2) {` and `\Alas` ...

Comment: that's something that I just added to see what happened XD. @TedLyngmo. But I think is wrong

Comment: I'm trying to get the "Ready for the fight" in my console

Comment: Ok, I reformatted the code and removed those two minor problems.

Comment: In what situation do you want to print "Ready for the fight"? The question says when XP is greater than 5, but the if statement says if Level == 2

Comment: when the player reaches level 2, so it's equal to the dragon level (that is level 2) @Korosia

Comment: because I wanted to make it short so I don't have to reach level 5 to see if I have it right or wrong

Comment: `while(gameRunning == true) {
        Player p(true);` - You create a new hero player in each iteration. That seems wrong. All experience and levels gains will be reset back to a newly created `Player`.

Comment: ... and `if(p.lvl == 2)` should probably be `if(p.lvl >= 2)` - I guess the player should be able to fight the dragon even if the player has a higher level than the dragon?

Comment: yes, that's correct @TedLyngmo

Comment: One more detail: You should seed the pseudo random number generator, i.e., call `srand()`, only once for the complete programs execution. Call it once when the program starts and never again. If you are using C++11 or newer, you should use the [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library instead of `srand()` and `rand()`.

Comment: You might also consider making the check `if(p.lvl >= d.lvl)`. That way if you decide to change the level of your dragon in future, you only need to update one place

Comment: while(gameRunning == true) { Player p(true); - You create a new hero player in each iteration. That seems wrong. All experience and levels gains will be reset back to a newly created Player. – @TedLyngmo . Yes I think this is the problem, how can I solve it?

Comment: If you move the creation of Player outside the loop, it will persist across iterations. However, now you've deleted the code, this question doesn't fit the format for Stack Overflow and is likely to be closed. If you could add a small amount of code that just shows the player class being created in the while loop, increasing the level, and then being reset on the next loop, it would become we can provide a proper answer to.

Comment: @Lucas Isn't this question answered?

Answer (score 2):

```
while(gameRunning == true) {
    Player p(true);
```

You create a new hero player in each iteration. All experience and levels gained will be reset back to a newly created `Player`.

Create the `Player` before the loop:

```
Player p(true);
while(gameRunning == true) {
```

If you want the player to be able to fight the dragon if he/she is *at least* at the same level as the dragon, change the condition from `if(p.lvl == 2)` to `if(p.lvl >= d.lvl)`.

You should seed the pseudo random number generator, i.e., call `srand()`, only once during the programs execution. Call it once when the program starts and never again.

If you are using C++11 or newer, you should use the [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library instead of `srand()` and `rand()`. The same rule applies for those modern generators. Only seed them once.

A function to create a random number could look like this:

```
#include <random>

// A function to return a random number generator.
inline std::mt19937& generator() {
    // the generator will only be seeded once since it's static
    static std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
    return gen;
}

// A function to generate int:s in the range [min, max]
int my_rand(int min, int max) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(min, max);
    return dist(generator());
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys, for all your help.

Comment: @Lucas You should probably leave this question unedited - and accept my answer if that made you solve the problem in your question.